# How to test a ionic Webcomponent in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, ionic4

i encounter the fowlling problem while writing tests for one of my components, that uses ionic4-components.

I have a really simple component, like this:

```
export class SelectedBadgetComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() public all: number = 0;
  @Input() public selected: number = 0;

  public color: string = "light"

  constructor() {

  }

  update() {
    if(this.selected > 0) {
      this.color = 'secondary'
      return
    }
    this.color = 'light'
    return;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.update();
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.update();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <ion-badge [color]="color" item-end>
      {{ selected }} / {{ all }}
    </ion-badge>
</div>
```

This component is used to show a badge of selected items. Something like this [ 2 / 10 ] (two of ten items are selected). Also it changes the classes for if the selected count is bigger than 1.

My test for this component which works fine in ionic3:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SelectedBadgetComponent);

  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  component.all = 5
  component.selected = 1

  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should have the class "ion-color-secondary"', () => {
  const badge = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ion-badge');
  expect(badge.classList.contains('ion-color-secondary')).toBe(true);
});
```

The problem occurs at the expectation. The given class is never set. When I debug this test I can see that while the expectation is being checked the class was actually not set, but some time then later it is set. I guess it's because the test doesn't wait until the webcomponent "ion-badge " is rendered.

How can I setup my test to wait until all children in the template are fully rendered?

I tried fixture.whenStable() which has no effect. Additionally, I added the CustomElement Schema ( `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` ) to my test, which is not very helpful either.

EDIT:

With this hack, the test is working - however, it is not a suitable solution in my opinion:

```
it('should have the class "ion-color-secondary"', async(() => {
  setTimeout(x => {
    const badge = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ion-badge');
    expect(badge.classList.contains('ion-color-secondary')).toBe(true);
  }, 2000)
}));
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue (both tests remain false for me)  In fact, I do not see any classes being added to this tag, could it be from code you have not yet shown?  Please see this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54177277?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts).  Please Fork this to your own StackBlitz account so you can edit it, update with your correct info and post back your new link to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @dmcgrandle Hi, in your StackBlitz some parts of ionic dont load. You can understand that with this 403 Error: `ionic.js:5 GET https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/ionic/ionic.mwduvpmm.js 403 ()` - thats the reason that both tests are failing, because the ionic-webcomponents are not rendered. I I try to setup an working Project on Stackbliz but encounter the same issue when i try to add ionic as dependencie: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-testing-ae2m9g . I'll let you know when I've managed to load ionic correctly